# Autocomplete Feature

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

We have the site which is using jquery 1.2.6 and jquery UI which is an older version. Right now we need to introduce Autocomplete feature. I have implemented it and it works but the problem is other UI features like Tabs doesnt work. I think there is a version conflict. Is there any way i can use the autocomplete feature UI lib alone in a seperate JS file.

OR

Do I need to upgrade the jquery and UI version to the latest?

Please suggest.

Baskar

Comment: which auto complete solution have you tried?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/default.html. I tried using the default jquery autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

From the source of autocomplete demo page, I noticed this;

```
<script src="../../jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
```

There will be some incompatibility with some older versions.

Comment: So How do i fix this. Upgrade the jquery UI to 1.8 for the whole site?